# How do I finish this roof/attic space?

Tags: ceiling, roof, finishing

I hope you can help with a question.

I have an unfinished room in my house that doesn’t have any insulation and and anything on the underside of the roof (sorry for not knowing the name of this space)

I want to use this room for storage so it doesn’t need to be finished as such or insulated to be honest, I just want to stop the dust/dirt/bugs getting into it. I’ve fixed some blue tarp with staples to the roof rafters but I’m starting to see fine dust still coming through. I want a better solution fo this and rather than tacking up some plastic, is there another reasonably priced choice? I rent so don’t want to plasterboard it out etc.

I’ve attached a picture that might hope me explain :)[image]

Comment: As a renter, a tarp that you nail/screw up, then remove before you move out is about the only improvement you can/should think about making unless you get the permission of the land lord. If you decide to do something more permanent, make sure you have the landlord's permission _in writing_ before doing so, and maybe negotiate the price of materials out of one month's rent.

Comment: Finishing is the solution...

Answer (score 0):

1/8" plywood is dirt cheap (maybe cheaper than your tarp even), light, and maybe flexible enough to get up there in one piece. You would probably have to chop it up, though. There should be space at the ends so that fresh air can move between the roof and the plywood. Your staples would hold it up temporarily, but you should probably use some 1-1/4" or so screws to permanently attach it.